# Defining Get and Set Behavior for Reference Returning Accessor

Tags: c++, interface, reference, operator-overloading

As part of a couple larger projects I’m working on developing a matrix template class which dynamically allocates blocks only when a value for an element in a block is altered from a defined initializer value. This class is going to be used in some fairly complex math so I’m trying to keep the interface as simple and intuitive as possible. I wanted to be able to use operator(row, col) to access matrix elements by reference instead of using get(row, col) and set(element) methods.

This became problematic however as due to the allocation behavior the actions for set and get need to be different and need to test the value being set against the initializer value. This can’t be done just returning a reference so I made a helper class which contains the reference and can be converted to the correct data type, and returned that. This is the structure of the interface:

```
template <class T>
class Container{

public:

    // Element class which contains a reference to a data element
    class Element{

    public:

        // Constructor -- Initialize the element reference
        Element(T & element) :  _element(element){}

        // Assignment operator -- SET
        Element & operator=(const T & that){
            _element = that;
            return *this;
        }

        // Element to element assignment -- GET that, SET this
        Element & operator=(const Element & that){
            this->_element = that._element;
            return *this;
        }

        // Implicit conversion operator -- GET
        operator T(){
            return _element;
        }

    private :

        T & _element; // Element reference

    };

    // Return an element class containing a reference to the element
    Element operator()(int index){
        return Element(_data[index]);;
    }

private:

    T _data[10];

};
```

It relies on implicit conversion to be able to use the returned Element class as if it were of type T. I tested it and it seems to work fine for basic assignment and arithmetic operations on base types but for operators such as incrementing and binary shifts the implicit conversion isn’t made and the operation results in a compiler error. And I’d assume I’d find a host of further issues trying to use it with T as a class structure, pointer, etc.

That, along with the fact that seems like very bad practice to rely on implicit conversion for the correction functioning of a class, makes me think I need to come up with another approach. Is there any way I can fix my current approach? Some other approach that I might take? Or should I just give up on this and make the operator(row, col) as always allocating with get and set methods allocating only when necessary?

Answer (score 0):

There's only so much magic you can do for you.

I want to first point you to [Blitz++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/blitz/) and [Thrust](http://thrust.github.com/) as some good didactic examples. In the first case, those "magic references" are heavily used to access regions of the data through subarrays, among other things. The second case is used to safely access data from other memory spaces (such as in the GPU), dealing with data download/uploads automatically.

I would recommend focusing on the common usage; is your container being used mostly to hold scalar values? Then just provide the common arithmetic operations such as ++, +=, etc that forward to the actual implementations. You'll see that's the approach used in [2](http://thrust.github.com/). The downside is it's a bit more inconvenient to access members of the internal data - but if that's an uncommon scenario, it would be a good trade-off.

Comment: In the projects I’m currently working on it’s going to be used for procedural generation and 2d single processing, this will be all scalar values, so just overloading/forwarding the operators would be an option, but I was really hoping to make this more universal so I could use it in other scenarios where it would hold class structures.